# Как сделать свою галочку с закругленными углами для radio инпута (input) CSS

Tags: css, css3, checkbox, radio-input

Как сделать такую галочку для как на картинке (сверху слева первая), но с закругленными углами?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<input type='radio' />
```

Именно **галочка** закругленная.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что бы стилизовать такой элемент как `input`, вне зависимости от его типа, вначале стоит обнулить дефолтные стили, которые могут быть добавлены браузером.

Далее есть несколько вариантов решения Вашей задачи, мой выбор это воспользоваться единственным [псевдо-элементом](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) и ограничить его зону видимости по размеру родителя, при помощи свойства [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) со значением hidden.

В принципе это все для input'a с ровными краями.

Чуть сложнее будет сделать так ***что бы галочка стала закругленной***, здесь нам помогут функции [линейного](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) и [радиального](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient) градиента.

Вот что получилось:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Живой пример можно посмотреть ниже:

```css
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content, max-content;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  margin: 30px;
}

div > input {
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 46px;
  height: 46px;
  font: inherit;
  letter-spacing: unset;
  word-spacing: unset;
  line-height: 1;
  text-shadow: none;
  text-align: unset;
  writing-mode: unset;
  text-rendering: unset;
  text-indent: 0;
  color: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: unset;
  padding: 0;
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-sizing: unset;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div > input:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

div > input::after {
  content: "";
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

div > input:first-child::after {
  width: 20px;
  height: 28px;
  border-right: 3px solid black;
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: -5px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

div > input:nth-of-type(2)::after {
  --color: black;
  --width: 70px;
  --height: 50px;
  --thick: 9px;
  --radius: 10px; 
  height: var(--height);
  width: var(--width);
  border-bottom-left-radius: var(--radius);
  background: 
     radial-gradient(farthest-side at top right, transparent 97%, var(--color) 100%) bottom calc(var(--thick) - 0.5px) left calc(var(--thick) - 0.5px) / calc(var(--thick) * 0.8) calc(var(--thick) * 0.8), 
     radial-gradient(farthest-side, var(--color) 99%, transparent 100%) top left / var(--thick) var(--thick), 
     radial-gradient(farthest-side, var(--color) 99%, transparent 100%) bottom right / var(--thick) var(--thick), 
     linear-gradient(var(--color), var(--color)) left bottom / var(--thick) calc(100% - var(--thick) / 2), 
     linear-gradient(var(--color), var(--color)) left bottom/calc(100% - var(--thick) / 2) var(--thick);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-top: -4px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.4);
}

div > input:checked::after {
  display: block;
}

div > p {
  grid-column: 2 / 2;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  <input type="radio" name="test" />
  <p>Ровные края</p>
  <input type="radio" name="test" />
  <p>Закругленные края</p>
</div>
```

Comment: В очередной раз огромнок вам спасибо! Особенно за то что расписываете все подробно

Answer (score 6):

Будет проще собрать его из двух составных закругленных прямоугольников + `transform: rotate()` на подходящие углы... Числа подобрал на глаз:

```css
.radio {
  display: none;
}

.pseudo-radio {
  font-size: 100px;
  /* Что прикольно, всё остальное будет регулироваться относительно этого размера */
  
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  
  border: 2px solid #929;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio:checked + .pseudo-radio::before,
.radio:checked + .pseudo-radio::after {
  display: block;
}

.pseudo-radio::before,
.pseudo-radio::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  
  bottom: 0.28em;
  left: 0.05em;
  transform: rotate(40deg);
  
  width: 0.6em;
  height: 0.2em;
  
  background-color: #f80;
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.pseudo-radio::after {  
  bottom: 0.4em;
  left: 0.28em;
  transform: rotate(-60deg);
  
  width: 0.8em;
  height: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="radio" name="bubu" checked>
  <span class="pseudo-radio"></span>
</label>
  
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="radio" name="bubu">
  <span class="pseudo-radio"></span>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" class="radio" name="bubu">
  <span class="pseudo-radio"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

Цвета если что подправите.

```css
/* Customize the label (the container) */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #fff;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid #2196F3;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="container">INput
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Я хотела именно галочку) закруглит квадрат проблем нет

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на чистом CSS

```css
.input-radio {
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-radio input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.input-radio .-custom {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #cacaca;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.input-radio .-custom::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 16px);
  height: calc(100% - 16px);
  background: #3c8dbc;
  margin: 8px;
}

.input-radio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .-custom::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  background: transparent !important;
  border: 6px solid #3c8dbc;
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.input-radio .-custom:hover,
.input-radio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .-custom:hover::before {
  border-color: #0076c3;
}

.input-radio .-custom:hover::before  {
  background: #0076c3;
}

.input-radio.--border-radius .-custom {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.input-radio.--border-radius-v2 .-custom {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.input-radio.--border-radius-v2 input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) ~ .-custom::before {
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.input-radio.--circle .-custom,
.input-radio.--circle input[type="radio"]:not(:checked) ~ .-custom::before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label for="input00" class="input-radio">
  <input id="input00" type="radio" name="i0[]">
  <div class="-custom"></div>
</label>

<label for="input01" class="input-radio">
  <input id="input01" type="radio" name="i0[]" checked>
  <div class="-custom"></div>
</label>
<br>
<label for="input10" class="input-radio --border-radius">
  <input id="input10" type="radio" name="i1[]">
  <div class="-custom"></div>
</label>

<label for="input11" class="input-radio --border-radius">
  <input id="input11" type="radio" name="i1[]" checked>
  <div class="-custom"></div>
</label>
<br>
<label for="input20" class="input-radio --border-radius-v2">
  <input id="input20" type="radio" name="i2[]">
  <div class="-custom"></div>
</label>

<label for="input21" class="input-radio --border-radius-v2">
  <input id="input21" type="radio" name="i2[]" checked>
  <div class="-custom"></div>
</label>
<br>
<label for="input30" class="input-radio --circle">
  <input id="input30" type="radio" name="i3[]">
  <div class="-custom"></div>
</label>

<label for="input31" class="input-radio --circle">
  <input id="input31" type="radio" name="i3[]" checked>
  <div class="-custom"></div>
</label>
```

UPD: Почему-то не проверил тогда на работоспособности.
ID не был уникальным и в результате не работало.